# Read date of file creation from within a zip file using FME

Tags: fme-form

I have a simple process that downloads a file from an FTP site and unzips the contents to a folder. Unfortunately the date of the file once unzipped is recorded as the date when the fmw was run but I need to get the date of the file itself. Is this possible?

The process
[image]

The result

[image]

But looking at the zip file we see the date that we need.
[image]

I noticed the zip extractor has a `_creation_instance` can this be captured into a variable (assuming it is the date we need)?

**Is there a parameter in the ZipExtractor (or other plugins) that allows me to capture the date of the files within it?**

UPDATE:
Based on the responses I tried the following but the powershell doesn't run from FME and without it I get the wrong date values.
[image]

Comment: I would have a look at using a PythonCaller and using Python to extract the dates of the files. You can possibly use the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) module and extract the dates from the archive members using zipinfo. `_creation_instance` comes from your Creator transformer.

Comment: filepropertyextractor (fme hub) does this https://hub.safe.com/publishers/pacific-spatial-solutions/transformers/filepropertyextractor  (use "_file_ctime" aka creation date)

Comment: @Mapperz this works if we use powershell to unzip the files but if we use any of the FME unizp modules it has `_file_mtime/ctime` as the current date. I tried a SystemCaller with `powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compressio
n.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("J:\Property Update FME Model\Input\RC.zip", "J:\Property Update FME Model\Input\RC"); }"` but it doesn't run (i tried connecting it to a Creator as well.

Comment: I believe the unzipping in fme extracts to a temp folder as https://hub.safe.com/publishers/safe-lab/transformers/unzipper does - would contact safe support they will get you a support answer

Comment: I have reported the date issue as a support ticket and also worked out the problem with powershell -needed `'` and not `"` to specify the zip source and out folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the 2 replies I have worked out a solution by bypassing the FME unzipper and reported the issue to FME and the publisher.

Basically I use powershell from a system caller and then filepropertyextractor.

[image]

SystemCaller is `powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('J:\Property Update FME Model\Input\RC.zip', 'J:\Property Update FME Model\Input\RC'); }"`